# Customize the search display template to show picture with the results

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template, content-search-web-part

I'm using contents web parts to get documents from specific document library.

And I already customized `Item_Default.html` in order to add lines and show discriptions next to Managed Properties.

Now the contents web parts looks like this.

```
=========================

Title

Last Modified Date [LastModifiedTime]

Editor [EditorOWSUSER]

All access [ViewsLifeTime] Recent Access [ViewsLast3Days] 

=========================
```

However, what I really wanted to do is to put picture on the left side....(and lines on the right side)

That's why at first, I tried to customize `Item_Picture3lines.html` of contents web parts display template. But I gave up customizing to show discriptions next to Managed Properties....

Does anybody know how to customize search template to show picture with search results like what i want?

Or anybody know how to customize `Item_Picture3lines.html` to put strings/discriptions of Managed properties?

Here is that template I customized and renamed `Item_Custom.html` based on `Item_Default.html`.

I'm Japanese so there are some Japanese words in the template...sorry

```
 Blockquote

<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>Customized Template</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">This shows Title, Last Modified Date, Editor,  All access and recent access for document. </mso:MasterPageDescription>

<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#Content Web Parts;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>

<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title', 'EditorOWSUSER':EditorOWSUSER', 'LastModifiedTime:'LastModifiedTime', 'ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime', 'ViewsLast3Days':'ViewsLast3Days','SecondaryFileExtension','ContentTypeId'
</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://[URL]/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Custom.html, 正常に変換されました。</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
<mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_Custom">

<!--#_ 

    //Get Title
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem.Title; 
    var titleHtml = String.format('<a href="{0}" title="{1}" >{2}</a>', $urlHtmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Path), $htmlEncode(title), $htmlEncode(title));

    //Get Editor
    var editorHtml = "";
    if (!$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.EditorOWSUSER)){
        var editorIdentifiers = ctx.CurrentItem.EditorOWSUSER.split(" | ");
             if(!$isNull(editorIdentifiers[1]))
             {
                 editorHtml = "Editor " + editorIdentifiers[1];
             }
    };


    //Get Last ModifiedTime
    var lastModifiedTime = ctx.CurrentItem.LastModifiedTime;
    var lastModifiedTimeHtml = "Last Modifed Date " + lastModifiedTime.getFullYear() + "年" + (lastModifiedTime.getMonth() + 1) + "月" + lastModifiedTime.getDate() +"日";

    //Get ViesLifeTime
    var ViewsLifeTime = ctx.CurrentItem.ViewsLifeTime;
    var ViewsLifeTimeHtml = " All access " + ViewsLifeTime;


    //Get ViewsLast3Days
    var ViewsLast3Days = ctx.CurrentItem.ViewsLast3Days;
    var ViewsLast3DaysHtml = " Recent Access (" + ViewsLast3Days + " )";

_#-->




<h3 class="ms-srch-ellipsis">_#=titleHtml=#_</h3><!-- Title -->
<div>    <span>_#=editorHtml=#_</span><!-- Editor --><br>
  <span>_#=lastModifiedTimeHtml=#_</span><!-- Last Modified Date --><br>
         <span>_#=ViewsLifeTimeHtml=#_</span><!-- All access -->
         <span>_#=ViewsLast3DaysHtml=#_</span><!-- Recent access -->
</div>


<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
            var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
            var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
   var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
   var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
            $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
   if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
   }
   ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
            ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data-displaytemplate="DefaultItem" class="ms-srch-item" onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">
    _#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
            </div>
<!--#_ 
        } 
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add static pictures or you want this pictures to be fetched from somewhere, I had my pictures uploaded in a list please check the way I have done it.

```
<span ><img src="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.ProfilePhoto =#_" height="150px" width="150px" /></span><br/><br/>
```

If you are using any specific image you can replace the url in "src". Make sure you have your image uploaded in the SharePoint Library of the current site.

Comment: Hi Akarsh Thank you for your comment. If this is possible, I want fetch pictures from document library column.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch it from anywhere, but make sure you do a full crawl and make a managed propety from Search. So you can fetch the value using that property as below.

```
<span ><img src="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.ProfilePhoto =#_" height="150px" width="150px" /></span><br/><br/>
```

ProfilePhoto  is the Managed property you create in search mapping to the column where your link is in the document Library. use this property and you will get Photo.